# Blender Blendshape meshes, UVs, and textures

Tags: uv, shape-keys

Here is what I want to achieve

Input: Three face models that are correctly UV mapped different textures.

Goal: Create a blendshape and animate between them.

Say A is a face with mouth and eyes closed, B is a face with eyes open, and C is a face with mouth open.

Then for, A(0%), B(50%), C(50%), I want eyes and mouth half open, and this can be achieved by simply using shape key. Morphing 3 textures are also possible by changing the balance of diffuse of 3 materials.

But the problem here is that it uses the UV coordinates of A, not blending of B and C, so now the morphed texture doesn't make sense.

Is there any way to solve this? eg. something like shape key for UVs?

Answer (score -1):

You already have the MESH part covered in your setup (standard) shapes. Good.

Now you also need to setup drivers to the SHADER aspect of this.

And it´s due with a simple FACTOR setup (greater than) Evaluation. If it returns a number above ZERO, expression is true, it SHOWS the texture. If it´s false, return TRANSPARENT (or default texture).
You may thank me enough to have searched for you this jewel, and thank you for voting me up as the answer.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0glf-acMvcw